# Why does this expression evaluate to 4 (call/cc)

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

Sorry this simple continuation example evaluates to 4, but I could not figure out why:

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (k)
    (* 5 (k 4))))
```

Chez Scheme 9.5.3

Answer (score 1):

`call/cc` lets you get the advantages of continuation passing style without having to write it in continuation passing style. eg.

```
(define (cars lsts)
  (define (cars lsts k)
    (cond ((null? lsts) (k '()))
          ((null? (car lsts)) '())
          (else (cars (cdr lsts)
                      (lambda (r) 
                        (k (cons (caar lsts) r)))))))
  (cars lsts values))

;; eg
(cars '())            ; ==> ()
(cars '((1) (2) (3))) ; ==> (1 2 3)
(cars '((1) (2) ()))  ; ==> ()
```

Can be written like this:

```
(define (cars lsts)
  (call/cc 
   (lambda (bail)
     (define (cars lsts)
       (cond ((null? lsts) '())
             ((null? (car lsts)) (bail '()))
             (else (cons (caar lsts) (cars (cdr lsts))))))
     (cars lsts))))
```

`call/cc&` looks like this in CPS:

```
(define (call/cc& proc k)
  (define (exit& v ignored-k)
    (k v))
  (proc exit& k))
```

And your simple example can easily be rewritten to continuation passing style:

```
(call/cc& (lambda (k& real-k)
            (k& 4 (lambda (res)
                    (*& 5 res real-k))))
          display)
```

So looking at that the `ignore-k` gets ignored and 4 gets passed to the continuation of `call/cc&` which I have put `display` which then displays `4` in the repl.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain you by writing a code with the same semantics by using CPS.

```
((lambda (k)
   (k 4
      (lambda (v)
        (* 5 v))))
 (lambda (result stack)
   ;; this continuation will drop the stack
   result))
```

After you call the continuation K, you also call it using the remained stack, but the stack is dropped.

Had you took into account the remaining stack you would have had:

```
((lambda (k)
   (k 4
      (lambda (v)
        (* 5 v))))
 (lambda (result stack)
   ;; this continuation will consider the stacked computation
   (stack result)))
```

and in this case the result would have been 20.

But in the semantics from your code, by calling the continuation, you dropped the stack, the not-finished computation.

Answer (score 0):

The continuation will return with the value passed to it `(k 4)`, so `4` is the return value.